# Ho to use third party library and declaration file?

Tags: typescript, bson

For my application I want to use a BSON. On the c++ server side I'm using mongodb bsoncxx so I decided to use the similar library in the browser. I found it [here](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson). Next I found a declaration file for this library [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/bson).

I downloaded [this code](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/tree/1.0-branch/lib/bson) and put it into the `third_party/bson` folder in my project. Next I downloaded a [declaration file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/bson/index.d.ts), renamed it to `bson.d.ts` and put into the same `third_party/bson` folder.

In `Main.ts` I wrote:

```
import * as bson from './third_party/bson/bson';
let BSON = new bson.BSON();
```

On build I have this error:

```
scripts/third_party/bson/bson.d.ts(7,1): error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
scripts/third_party/bson/bson.d.ts(27,100): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
scripts/third_party/bson/bson.d.ts(28,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
scripts/third_party/bson/bson.d.ts(40,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
scripts/third_party/bson/bson.d.ts(47,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
scripts/third_party/bson/bson.d.ts(51,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
scripts/third_party/bson/bson.d.ts(113,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
```

What is `node`, why do I need it, how can I get it and where should I put it?

Is there any way to get a library with all dependencies at once?

Comment: Are you using npm?

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using?

Comment: since the error comes from declaration file, you can use [skipLibCheck](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: @Paarth I'm using tsc 2.2.2. Yes, I have npm installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install node typescript definitions with

```
npm i @types/node --save-dev
```

and be sure to have this on your **tsconfig.json** file.

```
"compilerOptions": {
  [...]
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `npm i` tells me `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/nc/package.json'`

Comment: It is because you have not initialized your `package.json`. You have to do `npm init` before in your repo directory.